# how to read firmware.bin file through UART?

Tags: arm, embedded, embedded-resource, uart, firmware

i have to read firmware.bin file through UART, File size 50,000 byte.i write code but its shows garbage value while reading the file.

how i can read firmware.bin file of size 50,000 byte.? i use ARM cortex controller for programming.

i able to read .txt file of size less than 150 byte but when file size goes higher than 150 byte its read garbage value. and my task is to read 50,000 byte file which is binary file .bin

```
void read file()
{
UART1_TxString("AT+QFOPEN=\"RAM:FIRMWARE.BIN\",2\r");
                                              //2:only read for opend file.
WaitForExpectedResponse("+QFOPEN:",1000);    // timeout 1000ms       
                                     //in response +QFOPEN: 134072 filehandler
UART1_TxString("AT+QFREAD=134072\r");
connect = WaitForConnectResponse("CONNECT",60000); // timeout 60000ms
                       // in response CONNECT 50000 (i.e.filesize 50,000 byte)
while(connect)
{    
   int i=0,j=0;
   char* param = strchr(UART1Buffer, 'T') + (strlen(size_buff)+2);
          // UART1Buffer its UART-Buffer of size 160.
          // size_buff store file size to be read in string (50000)
          // size_int  store file size to be read in integer(50000)
 for(i=0;i<size_int;i++){           
        UART2_Printf(" %c ",*param);// print UART-BUFFER-DATA
  }
 }
}
void UART1_IRQHandler ( void ) 
{
  uint8_t IIRValue, LSRValue;
  uint8_t Dummy = Dummy;

  IIRValue = LPC_UART1->IIR;

  IIRValue >>= 1;           /* skip pending bit in IIR */
  IIRValue &= 0x07;         /* check bit 1~3, interrupt identification */
  if ( IIRValue == IIR_RLS )        /* Receive Line Status */
  {
    LSRValue = LPC_UART1->LSR;

    if ( LSRValue & (LSR_OE|LSR_PE|LSR_FE|LSR_RXFE|LSR_BI) )
    {
      UART1Status = LSRValue;
      Dummy = LPC_UART1->RBR;       /* Dummy read on RX to clear 
                                interrupt, then bail out */
      return;
    }
    if ( LSRValue & LSR_RDR )   /* Receive Data Ready */            
    {
      UART1Buffer[UART1Count] = LPC_UART1->RBR;
      UART1Count++;
      if ( UART1Count == BUFSIZE )  // BUFSIZE= 160
      {
        UART1Count = 0;     /* buffer overflow */
      } 
    }
  }
  else if ( IIRValue == IIR_RDA )   /* Receive Data Available */
  {
    UART1Buffer[UART1Count] = LPC_UART1->RBR;
    UART1Count++;
    if ( UART1Count == BUFSIZE )
    {
      UART1Count = 0;       /* buffer overflow */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that you don't protect the buffer anywhere, nor other variables shared with the ISR. So you have race condition bugs all over the place.

Comment: Where do you declare the variables? Post a [mcve] and also please fix indention while you're at it.

Comment: If the data is binary and therefore not necessarily printable, you should use `%2X` rather than the `%c` format specifier.  You also need to post _real_ code - the very first line is invalid, so this is certainly not the code you are running - because it won't compile.  If `size_int` is truly  50000 as in the comment, but the buffer is only 160 characters, the loop is clearly nonsense, you need to wait for data to be written to the buffer before you try printing it.  Even then the  `param` pointer is not modified, so does not even iterate the buffer.  This code is not doing even what you say.

Comment: You are writing to the buffer while you are trying to read from it.  Use a ring buffer with separate indexes for read and write, the ISR writes to `buffer[write_idx]`, while the read function reads from  `buffer[read_idx]`.  And remember that you can read the buffer faster then the ISR will fill it, so sometimes (most of the time) it will be empty - i.e. you have to wait for the data not just assume it is there by magic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To buffer data that will be asynchronously read in some other context (between an ISR and a "normal" thread as in this case, you should use a FIFO or ring buffer in order that the ISR can continue to write to the buffer while the normal thread is reading and processing it.  For example, given:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

#define BUFFLEN ((uint8_t)128u)               // Must be a power of 2
#define BUFFMODMASK ((uint8_t)(BUFFLEN - 1))  // modulo BUFFLEN mask

typedef volatile struct
{
    uint8_t write_idx ;
    uint8_t read_idx ;
    atomic_int count ;
    uint8_t data[BUFFLEN] ;
} tRingBuf ;

void ringBufPut( tRingBuf* buffer, uint8_t ch )
{
    if( buffer->count < BUFFLEN )
    {
        buffer->data[buffer->write_idx++] = ch ;
        buffer->write_idx &= BUFFMODMASK ;
        buffer->count++ ;
    }
}

int ringBufGet( tRingBuf* buffer )
{
    int ch = -1 ;
    if( buffer->count > 0 )
    {
        ch =  (int)buffer->data[buffer->read_idx++] ;    
        buffer->read_idx &= BUFFMODMASK ;
        buffer->count-- ;
    }

    return ch ;
}

tRingBuf UART1RxBuffer = { 0, 0, 0, {0} } ;
```

Your ISR will then place data in the buffer thus:

```
ringBufPut( &UART1RxBuffer, LPC_UART1->RBR ) ;
```

Then your main thread can read the data thus:

```
for( int i = 0; i < size_int; i++ )
{           
    int ch = ringBufGet( &UART1RxBuffer ) ;
    if( ch > 0 )
    {
        uint8_t byte = (uint8_t)ch ;

        // ... do something with the data here
        // For example...
        UART2_Printf( "%02X", (unsigned)byte ) ;
    }
}
```

You would do well perhaps to implement the UART Tx in the same way (reversing the put/get) for all UARTs - your ISR only deals with Rx currently. Fully buffered I/O will lead to more deterministic timing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response clifford. Am almost very nearer what i need to be do.
I tried using ring buffer its working and almost i done with this.

But when i try reading the large file (48kB) **Update.BIN** file,
it is reading complete file, but when i compare this read file with **actual file**, it is observed the data loss and mismatch of data
(Am attaching the actual file and what i read both herewith fyr).

File that i read through UART ring buffer : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/93k3i3r598jkxro/My_Read_file.log?dl=0

Actual file that i try to read : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmh5wyurrdvvtqx/Update.BIN.txt?dl=0

My code for ring buffer as below:

```
#define UART_RING_BUFSIZE 256
#define __BUF_MASK (UART_RING_BUFSIZE-1)
#define __BUF_IS_FULL(head, tail) ((tail&__BUF_MASK)==((head+1)&__BUF_MASK))
#define __BUF_WILL_FULL(head, tail) ((tail&__BUF_MASK)==((head+2)&__BUF_MASK))
#define __BUF_IS_EMPTY(head, tail) ((head&__BUF_MASK)==(tail&__BUF_MASK))
#define __BUF_RESET(bufidx) (bufidx=0)
#define __BUF_INCR(bufidx)  (bufidx=(bufidx+1)&__BUF_MASK)

typedef struct
{
    __IO uint32_t tx_head;                /*!< UART Tx ring buffer head index */
    __IO uint32_t tx_tail;                /*!< UART Tx ring buffer tail index */
    __IO uint32_t rx_head;                /*!< UART Rx ring buffer head index */
    __IO uint32_t rx_tail;                /*!< UART Rx ring buffer tail index */
    __IO uint8_t  tx[UART_RING_BUFSIZE];  /*!< UART Tx data ring buffer */
    __IO uint8_t  rx[UART_RING_BUFSIZE];  /*!< UART Rx data ring buffer */
} UART_RING_BUFFER_T;


// UART Ring buffer
UART_RING_BUFFER_T rb;

// Current Tx Interrupt enable state
__IO FlagStatus TxIntStat;
```

Interrupt IRQHandler :

```
void UART0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    uint32_t intsrc, tmp, tmp1;

    /* Determine the interrupt source */
    intsrc = UART_GetIntId(LPC_UART0);
    tmp = intsrc & UART_IIR_INTID_MASK;

    // Receive Line Status
    if (tmp == UART_IIR_INTID_RLS){
        // Check line status
        tmp1 = UART_GetLineStatus(LPC_UART0);
        // Mask out the Receive Ready and Transmit Holding empty status
        tmp1 &= (UART_LSR_OE | UART_LSR_PE | UART_LSR_FE \
                | UART_LSR_BI | UART_LSR_RXFE);
        // If any error exist
        if (tmp1) {
                UART_IntErr(tmp1);
        }
    }
    // Receive Data Available or Character time-out
    if ((tmp == UART_IIR_INTID_RDA) || (tmp == UART_IIR_INTID_CTI)){
            UART_IntReceive();
    }
    // Transmit Holding Empty
    if (tmp == UART_IIR_INTID_THRE){
            UART_IntTransmit();
    }
}
```

for receiving the data :

```
void UART_IntReceive(void)
{
    uint8_t temp;
    uint32_t recv_byte;

    while(1){

        recv_byte = UART_Receive((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, &temp, 1, NONE_BLOCKING);
        // If data received
        if (recv_byte){

            if (!__BUF_IS_FULL(rb.rx_head,rb.rx_tail)){
                rb.rx[rb.rx_head] = temp;
                __BUF_INCR(rb.rx_head);
            }
        }
        // no more data
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

for transmitting the data :

```
void UART_IntTransmit(void)
{
    // Disable THRE interrupt
    UART_IntConfig((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, UART_INTCFG_THRE, DISABLE);

    while (UART_CheckBusy((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0) == SET);

    while (!__BUF_IS_EMPTY(rb.tx_head,rb.tx_tail))
    {
        /* Move a piece of data into the transmit FIFO */
        if (UART_Send((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, (uint8_t *)&rb.tx[rb.tx_tail], 1, NONE_BLOCKING)){
        /* Update transmit ring FIFO tail pointer */
        __BUF_INCR(rb.tx_tail);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (__BUF_IS_EMPTY(rb.tx_head, rb.tx_tail)) {
        UART_IntConfig((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, UART_INTCFG_THRE, DISABLE);
        // Reset Tx Interrupt state
        TxIntStat = RESET;
    }
    else{
        // Set Tx Interrupt state
        TxIntStat = SET;
        UART_IntConfig((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, UART_INTCFG_THRE, ENABLE);
    }
}
void UART_IntErr(uint8_t bLSErrType)
{
    uint8_t test;
    // Loop forever
    while (1){
        // For testing purpose
        test = bLSErrType;
    }
}
```

UART Receive and Transmit Functions use in interrupts  :

```
uint32_t UART_Send(LPC_UART_TypeDef *UARTx, uint8_t *txbuf,
        uint32_t buflen, TRANSFER_BLOCK_Type flag)
{
    uint32_t bToSend, bSent, timeOut, fifo_cnt;
    uint8_t *pChar = txbuf;

    bToSend = buflen;

    // blocking mode
    if (flag == BLOCKING) {
        bSent = 0;
        while (bToSend){
            timeOut = UART_BLOCKING_TIMEOUT;
            // Wait for THR empty with timeout
            while (!(UARTx->LSR & UART_LSR_THRE)) {
                if (timeOut == 0) break;
                timeOut--;
            }
            // Time out!
            if(timeOut == 0) break;
            fifo_cnt = UART_TX_FIFO_SIZE;
            while (fifo_cnt && bToSend){
                UART_SendByte(UARTx, (*pChar++));
                fifo_cnt--;
                bToSend--;
                bSent++;
            }
        }
    }
    // None blocking mode
    else {
        bSent = 0;
        while (bToSend) {
            if (!(UARTx->LSR & UART_LSR_THRE)){
                break;
            }
            fifo_cnt = UART_TX_FIFO_SIZE;
            while (fifo_cnt && bToSend) {
                UART_SendByte(UARTx, (*pChar++));
                bToSend--;
                fifo_cnt--;
                bSent++;
            }
        }
    }
    return bSent;
}
uint32_t UART_Receive(LPC_UART_TypeDef *UARTx, uint8_t *rxbuf, \
        uint32_t buflen, TRANSFER_BLOCK_Type flag)
{
    uint32_t bToRecv, bRecv, timeOut;
    uint8_t *pChar = rxbuf;

    bToRecv = buflen;

    // Blocking mode
    if (flag == BLOCKING) {
        bRecv = 0;
        while (bToRecv){
            timeOut = UART_BLOCKING_TIMEOUT;
            while (!(UARTx->LSR & UART_LSR_RDR)){
                if (timeOut == 0) break;
                timeOut--;
            }
            // Time out!
            if(timeOut == 0) break;
            // Get data from the buffer
            (*pChar++) = UART_ReceiveByte(UARTx);
            bToRecv--;
            bRecv++;
        }
    }
    // None blocking mode
    else {
        bRecv = 0;
        while (bToRecv) {
            if (!(UARTx->LSR & UART_LSR_RDR)) {
                break;
            } else {
                (*pChar++) = UART_ReceiveByte(UARTx);
                bRecv++;
                bToRecv--;
            }
        }
    }
    return bRecv;
}
```

UART TX and RX functions:

```
uint32_t UARTSend(LPC_UART_TypeDef *UARTPort, uint8_t *txbuf, uint8_t buflen)
{
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) txbuf;
    uint32_t bytes = 0;

    UART_IntConfig(UARTPort, UART_INTCFG_THRE, DISABLE);

    while ((buflen > 0) && (!__BUF_IS_FULL(rb.tx_head, rb.tx_tail)))
    {
        /* Write data from buffer into ring buffer */
        rb.tx[rb.tx_head] = *data;
        data++;

        /* Increment head pointer */
        __BUF_INCR(rb.tx_head);

        bytes++;
        buflen--;
    }

    if (TxIntStat == RESET) {
        UART_IntTransmit();
    }
    else {
        UART_IntConfig(UARTPort, UART_INTCFG_THRE, ENABLE);
    }

    return bytes;
}

uint32_t UARTReceive(LPC_UART_TypeDef *UARTPort, uint8_t *rxbuf, uint8_t buflen)
{
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) rxbuf;
    uint32_t bytes = 0;

    UART_IntConfig(UARTPort, UART_INTCFG_RBR, DISABLE);


    while ((buflen > 0) && (!(__BUF_IS_EMPTY(rb.rx_head, rb.rx_tail))))
    {
        /* Read data from ring buffer into user buffer */
        *data = rb.rx[rb.rx_tail];
        data++;

        /* Update tail pointer */
        __BUF_INCR(rb.rx_tail);

        /* Increment data count and decrement buffer size count */
        bytes++;
        buflen--;
    }
    UART_IntConfig(UARTPort, UART_INTCFG_RBR, ENABLE);
    return bytes;
}
```

main function

```
void main(){

uint32_t idx=0, len[enter link description here][1]=0;
    __IO FlagStatus exitflag;
    uint8_t buffer[100]

// reset exit flag
    exitflag = RESET;
while (exitflag == RESET)
    {
        len = 0;
        while (len == 0)
        {
            len = UARTReceive((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        idx = 0;
        while (idx < len)
        {
          UARTSend((LPC_UART_TypeDef *)LPC_UART0, &buffer[idx], 1);
          idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also it is observed reading .txt file never missed any byte while reading. Only the issue while reading the .bin file.

kindly let me know where am going wrong.